# How can I achieve this 'WOW' scrolling effect

Tags: css, scroll, effect

A client of mine saw this awesome scrolling effect when clicking on a menu item: http://www.feedmusic.com/

I'm talking about the grey/purple overflow between the two anchor menu items. 
I've been Googeling around for hours and can't find anything like this. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's very simple to implement wow.js into project. Check this documentation: http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html and demo:http://codepen.io/syedrafeeq/pen/yEJKn

Answer (score 0):

It's singlepage application with disabled scrolling. I haven't experience with singlepage, but here are ideas which looks like it could work:

1. Create two divs between content one gray and second purple (or one with two colors in the background). Then create scrolling via js (jquery) on button click.
2. If it's ajax loaded, there could be only 3 divs: one with current content, one with gray/purple background and third with new content and js should place the divs to required places. But first solution should be easier.

Implementation is up to you.